# HttpURLConnection on android 2.3.5 and 2.3.6

Tags: android

After upgrade to android 2.3.5 and 2.3.6, the code for android
HttpURLConnection class: urlconn.connect(), urlconn.getOutputStream()
and urlconn.getInputStream() becomes very slow (each command takes
more than 5 second, under version 2.3.2 or 2.2 it just take less than
1 sec).
Does any one has the same situation?

My codes looks like this:

```
getUrl = new URL(url);
urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) getUrl.openConnection();

urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
urlConn.setRequestMethod(httpMethod.name());
urlConn.setConnectTimeout(HTTP_CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
urlConn.setReadTimeout(HTTP_READ_TIMEOUT);
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
if (requestBody != null)
       urlConn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(requestBody.length());
if (!(httpMethod == HttpMethod.GET))
       urlConn.setDoOutput(true);

urlConn.connect();

if (requestBody != null) {
       osw = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream());
       osw.write(requestBody);
       osw.flush();
}

in = urlConn.getInputStream();
buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int nRead;
byte[] data = new byte[256];
while ((nRead = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
       buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
}
buffer.flush();
responseBody = buffer.toByteArray();
responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
```

Regards,
Zheng

Comment: This is usually name resolution related, check your DNS settings and/or servers.

Comment: I'm struggling with similar issue since past few days. Please let me know if you find the solution. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Two bits of advice:

1. Insert logging statements after each HTTP operation. That way you can see which step is taking the most time.
2. Reading 256 bytes at a time from the InputStream is going to be rather inefficient. In my experience, an 8k buffer size (8192) works best on most devices and networks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it on separate thread.